# get array from the object using map in javascript. but getting array with undefined

Tags: javascript

I am using map to get the sub part of the array.

```js
var mappingobj = {"custom":[{"head":"202","sub":["302","303"]},{"head":"203","sub":["102"]}],"spec":[]};

var subids = mappingobj.custom.map(function(o, i) {
      if(o.head==202){
       return o.sub;
      }
});

console.log(subids);
```

I need to get only ["302","303"]. but i am getting the output as [Array[2], undefined].

Comment: You should be mapping after `Array#filter`

Comment: The undefined comes because only when your "non-strict equality" head matches 202 you return the sub, the other onces do not, so they return undefined

Comment: @rayon how to use filter with map. can u tell me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic Idea is that map is to get certain value out of array.
if you don't return anything in map by default undefined will be return and you will get undefined.So use filter to get desired object and than use map to get desired property of that object

```js
var mappingobj = {"custom":[{"head":"202","sub":["302","303"]},{"head":"203","sub":["102"]}],"spec":[]};

var subids = mappingobj.custom.filter(function(o, i) {
      if(o.head==202 && o.head){
       return o;
      }
}).reduce((acc,elem)=>{acc.push(...elem.sub); return acc;},[]);

console.log(subids);
```

Comment: yes exactly correct. but i want the single dimensional array can u help me like [302,303]

Comment: check updated code. Even if there are multiple head with given value it will merge all of them in one arrat

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this.

```js
var mappingobj = {
  "custom": [{
    "head": "202",
    "sub": ["302", "303"]
  }, {
    "head": "203",
    "sub": ["102"]
  }],
  "spec": []
};

var subids = mappingobj.custom.filter(function(o, i) {
  if (o.head == 202) {
    return o.sub;
  }
});

console.log(subids);
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: it will work dude, as you are already returning an array, try it out.

Comment: It will return array of objects, OP is expecting one dimensional array....

Answer (score 0):

You can find `indexOf` of `head` first and then get `sub` of `mapping.custom`

```js
var mappingobj = {"custom":[{"head":"202","sub":["302","303"]},{"head":"203","sub":["102"]}],"spec":[]};
var obj = mappingobj.custom;
var index = obj.map(function (e) { return e.head; }).indexOf("202");
console.log(obj[index].sub);
```